# Show that $\rho(A) \geq \max_{1\leq i \leq n}|a_{ii}|.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be normal. Show that $\rho(A) \geq \max_{1\leq i \leq n}|a_{ii}|,$ where $\rho(.)$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

I know that $\rho(A) \leq \sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^{^*}A)}:=\sigma_{\text{max}}(A)=||A||.$ Is there any relation between diagonal element and the eigenvalue? I know the relation with the trace but can not connect with each diagonal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It $A$ is a bounded operator on a Hilbert space (including the case of $n\times n$ matrices), one defines:

- the norm: $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|Ax\|$,
- the spectral radius: $\rho(A)=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|\lambda|$, and
- the numerical radius: $w(A)=\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle|$.

For every $A$
$$
  \rho(A)\leq w(A)\leq \|A\| \leq 2w(A).
  $$
but when $A$ is normal one has that
$$
  \rho(A) = w(A) =\|A\|.
  $$

Since a diagonal entry of an $n\times n$ matrix is given by $A_{ii}=\langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$, we then have
$$
  |a_{ii}| \leq w(A) = \rho(A),
  $$
provided $A$ is normal.

---

**EDIT**

**Lemma**.  If $A$ is a normal matrix, then the *numerical radius* of $A$ coincides with its *spectral radius*.

*Proof*. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors, with corresponding eigenvalues
$\{\lambda _i\}_{i=1}^n$.  For $\|x\|\leq 1$, we then have
$$
  \langle Ax, x\rangle  =
  \Big\langle A\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i\Big),\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i\big\rangle  =
  \Big\langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\lambda _ie_i,\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i\big\rangle  =
  \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\lambda _i.
  $$
Therefore
$$
  |\langle Ax, x\rangle | \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2|\lambda _i| \leq  \big (\sup_{1\leq i\leq n} |\lambda _i|\big ) \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 = \rho (A)\|x\|^2 \leq \rho (A).
  $$
Taking the supremum over $x$ we get
$$
  w(A) = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|\langle Ax, x\rangle | \leq  \rho (A).
  $$
On the other hand, for every $i≤n$ we have that
$$
  w(A) \geq  |\langle Ae_i, e_i\rangle | = |\langle \lambda _ie_i, e_i\rangle | = |\lambda _i|.
  $$
Taking the supremum over $i$ we get
$$
  w(A) \geq  \sup_{1≤i≤n} |\lambda _i| = \rho(A).
  $$
QED

Comment: Can you give me the proof of the equalities and the equalities when $A$ is normal? I know the proof that if $A$ is normal then we have an ONB consisting of eigenvectors and using this fact we can also prove that $\rho(A)=\sqrt{A^{*}A}$. Can you please edit and give me proof of that fact if this is short. Upon searching I found a paper "https://www.zu.edu.jo/UploadFile/PaperFiles/PaperFile_48_35.pdf" which was hard to read. Can you give me the necessary idea?

Comment: I can see the first two inequalities that is not sufficient for the proof of this problem. I am interested to know the rest. If you can help.

Comment: What is needed the most is to know why $\rho(A)=w(A)$ when $A$ is normal.

Comment: @Ri-Li, There you go!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Don't we have the fact that :
$ \rho(A) = \max_{ \Vert v \Vert \le 1} \Vert \langle  v, Av \rangle\Vert $  for any normal matrix $A$ ?
If this is true, isn't your problem solved?
**Disclaimer**: I don't know, just asking because to me it is feasible due to the fact that $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be true but I don't know the proof. I know the proof that if $A$ is normal then we have an ONB consisting of eigenvectors and using this fact we can also prove that $\rho(A)=\sqrt{A^{*}A}$. Can you please edit and give me proof of that fact if this is short. Upon searching I found a paper "https://www.zu.edu.jo/UploadFile/PaperFiles/PaperFile_48_35.pdf" which was hard to read for me.